# Is there a standard way of dealing with javascript only used in one view in MVC?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, templates

This is the first time I've tried MVC.  I am using Code Igniter for the MVC along with jQuery and jQueryUI for the front end.  I have the basic idea of MVC and I have a working site.  Conceptually, though, I want to make sure that I stay as rigid as possible with respect to the MVC idea.

I have a main skin view and then use `load->view("skin", $contents)` where `$contents` is an associative array containing other views.

As a result, I have one page (called "admin Console") in which the skin view is called and `$content` contains more HTML.  I want a jQueryUI dialog box to be used only on that page.  To create this, I have a `<script>` tag that contains the dialog box javascript in the admin console view.  This ends up with a `<script>` tag in the middle of a bunch of HTML that includes when the final page is rendered.

The end result of this is that I am lazy loading the javascript but it may result in multiple jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){...});` calls.

I have everything working, but I am not sure if my implementation is true to the MVC principles.  Is it better to use the method I am using in which the javascript is only loaded when it's being used or should I put the javascript somewhere else?  Am I making mountains out of mole hills?

---

My Relevant Controller Code:

```
function index(){
$tree = $this->mainModel->getUnitTreeMeta();
$treeOutput = $this->load->view('unit_tree', array('units' => $tree), TRUE);
$pages = $this->mainModel->getPages();

$console = $this->load->view('admin_console', array('units'=>$tree, 'pages'=>$pages), TRUE);

$content = array(
    'title'         =>  'Admin Console',
    'css'           =>  link_tag(array('href' => 'css/admin.css', 'rel' => 'stylesheet', 'type' => 'text/css', 'media'=> 'screen'))."\n",
    'navbar'        =>  'navbar',
    'content'       =>  $console,
    'rightSidebar'  =>  $treeOutput,
    'footer'        =>  ''
);

$this->load->view('skin', $content);
}
```

skin.php contains the line `<?=$content?>` which is the HTML/JS contained in the admin_console view:

```
<div>
    <div>
        ...
        <a href="" id="addUnit" class="smallLinks">Add a New Unit</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- DIALOG BOXES -->
<div id="addUnitDialog" title="Add A New Unit">
    <?php echo form_open('admin/add_unit'); ?>
    Unit Name: <br />
    <?php echo form_input("unitName", "");?>
    <br />
    Content: <br />
    <?php echo form_textarea("content", "");?>
    <?php echo  form_close();?>
    <div id="addUnitResponse"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#addUnitDialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            minWidth: 680,
            buttons: {
                "add Unit" : function(){
                    var unitName = $("input", this).val();
                    var content = $("textarea", this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "add_unit",
                        type : "POST",
                        success :function(){
                            location.reload();
                        },
                        error : function(){
                            $("#addUnitResponse").text("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }           
        });
        $("a#addUnit").click(function(){
            $( "#addUnitDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;       
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know, I'm even making my own framework. I'm looking at the title, it says Javascript, and i get hit by a bunch of PHP code.

Comment: @ultimatebuster: sorry, codeigniter MVC is php.  Should I revise the title?  The TL;DR is "does it matter where the javascript appears in relation to my views in an MVC pattern?"

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have backed off from my opinion that JS should never, ever appear in HTML. But, the way I've normally done this type of thing is include a "`if(isset(...`" block at the <head> of the view:

```
// You may choose to have non-array implementations...
if(isset($js_array))
{
    foreach($js_array as $file)
    {
        if(strpos($file, '.'))
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"$file\" />" . PHP_EOL;
        else
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$file</script>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The drawback here is that it requires the control to know about how the view is rendering different things. Of course, that could be fixed by creating a file, `admin.php` which has two lines in it:

```
 $js_array = array('/custom_js.js');
 require_once('skin.php'); //<-- will cause issues if your server does not 
                           //    allow short tags, but CodeIgniter is parsing 
                           //    them for you. (I find that bad anyway...)
```

You'd need to call `$this->load->view('admin', $content);`, but that is a minor change.

Comment: So in my case, I could use a bit of PHP to set a flag (or an array) that says "now that you are loading this, go ahead and load x.js".  Then x.js would be the code that I want run only with that view?  That's an interesting solution.  I'll try it out.

Comment: I've had plenty of times where I've conditionally assigned something in the view based on what has been sent by the Controller. It really seems like the only sane way to do things.